# Copy contents of active div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to to copy contents of clicked div to another div. I have list of video along with title and date. I need to play video and copy contents of clicked div to another.

So far i am able to play video but it always copies contents of first div only. how can i trap even of active div or one i click on.

Example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/9/)

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.Play-Video').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var URL = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.video-title').text($(this).text());
        var htm = '<iframe width="438" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';

        //$('#video_container').html(htm);
        // $('.video-title').html(htm);
            $(".video-title").html($(".title").html());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want something like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/11/)?

Comment: Do you want to change video on click links also ?

Comment: @Mr_Green. Yes something like that i can modify the rest to copy date part also .. thanks..

Comment: @Mr_Green. How to copy date also, i tried it just copies title part only..

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker First, I had misunderstood your question. I added the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually call like this:

```
$(".video-title").html($(this).children(".title").html());  //for changing title
$(".video-date").html($(this).children(".date").html());    //for changing date
```

instead of just

```
$(".video-title").html($(".title").html());  //this will look for all classes wit name ".title" present in the html code
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/17/) (*updated the fiddle*)

Comment: Thanks you updated link i was wondering why it is not working. This is what i want.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker using just `$(".title").html()` will look for all classes with class name `.title` in the html code. but you were actually willing to point the `.title` which is the children element of the **clicked** `.play-video` class element. I hope you understood my explanation. :)

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker if my post helped you then please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple...

Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/YtcDJ

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Play-Video').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var URL = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.video-title').text($(this).text());
        var htm = '<iframe width="438" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';
        $(".video-title").html($(".title", $(this)).html());
    });
});
```

I've changed: `$(".video-title").html($(".title").html());` 
into: `$(".video-title").html($(".title", $(this)).html());`

With this, the 'title' is fetched from the 'this' context.

Good luck with it!